# Match smiley emoticon except between ticks or triple ticks

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match a smiley emoticon (and others, but I can start here). Which I can do:

```
/:-\)/g
```

No big deal. I do not want to match the smiley when it is between a single ticks.

```
`
```

Or when it is in between triple ticks

````
```
````

So don't match:

```
`:-)`
```

Or

```
`some stuff :-) some other stuff`
```

And don't match

````
```
:-)
```
````

And when there is other stuff in there:

````
```
import somelib

x + 2
:-)
yada yada
```
````

My attempt was the following:

```
/(?!\`.*|\`\`\`.*):-\)(?!\`|\`\`\`)/gm
```

I tried doing a negative lookahead and skipping the tick with some stuff in between, but I can't seem to get it working.

To be clearer:

input:

```
:-)
```

**Should match**

input:

```
`:-)`
```

**Should not match**

input:

````
```
:-)
```
````

**Should not match**

input:

```
`something :-) something`
```

**Should not match**

input:

````
```
something
:-)
something
```
````

**Should not match**

In the end I want to replace the smiley with it's emoji: `\uD83D\uDE03`.

Comment: Skipping is not possible in JS regex. Match and capture - that is what you need - https://regex101.com/r/VDKDTT/1. The rest can be handled with the right code.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew so match the three cases, and then do the rest myself?

Comment: I cannot help any more as the question is unclear. What are you trying to achieve? Provide sample input and expected output.

Comment: just matching a smiley doesn't make sense without knowing at what positions it was matched/ignored

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Updated he description with what should match and what should not.

Comment: @Johnston: No, it does not help. What do you need to get *in the end*? It is clear what you need to differentiate 3 cases, and I already provided a regex that does that. The next action is to understand what you need to do.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I updated to show what I would like to get in the end. Does that help?

Comment: Yes, now it is easy to answer. So, only the emoticon outside of `\`` and `\`\`\`` should be replaced, right?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes. Correct

Comment: Here is the solution - https://jsfiddle.net/jv4L53fo/

Comment: That worked! Thank you! @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to skip a match in JS regex flavor. The common approach is to match and capture what you need to keep and just match what you need to replace.

Use

````
var regex = /(```[\s\S]*?```|`[\s\S]*?`)|:-\)/g;
var res = str.replace(regex, function($0,$1) {
  return $1 ? $1 : '\uD83D\uDE03';
  }
);
````

The regex will match and capture into Group 1 any texts in between a single or triple backticks and match the smiley in all other contexts where it will get replaced.